# Call external service from within Notion

Tags: notion-api

I would like to call a third party API from within a Notion database. Basically I would like the request to be sent based on the update of a status, e.g. if I change the status from "ready" to "in progress" I would like to automatically send an API request to an external third party.

Notion has am example on how to send an email using sendgrid, but I am at a loss on how to use this (not locally, but within the database).

Any help will be much appreciated.

I tried to use the template DB they offer, but I couldn't understand how to use it.

Comment: To confirm: I am only referring to third parties without an integration with Notion.